# PHP Soap Connection Periodic Failure

Tags: php, soap, salesforce

I'm using the Fore.com PHP toolkit for integrating with the SFDC API.

I have the app hosted in a client's office, and it is getting periodic errors where the connection times out, and can't reach the salesforce host.

The app runs fine on my laptop, regardless of the internet connection I'm using.  I've also used this library in numerous environments, so confident that this is not a code issue.

Can someone recommend a way I can analyze what's happening in terms of connectivity on this box, so I can prove/articulate the problem to the client's Sys Admin?  We're in a bit of a finger-pointing situation now, want to find a resolution.

I realize I can increase the timeout of the app, but for the app to be practical for the client, they can't be waiting long periods for the connections to be made while running through a wizard.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and when i contacted SFDC support, they mentioned that
this problem is because of the performance degradation on SFDC server.

When I check http://trust.salesforce.com to verify system status there was no record of degradation.

When asked, SFDC support mentioned that it was not mentioned on http://trust.salesforce.com it was for very short span.

They also recommended that calling PHP script should have retry mechanization so that it try 3 times or so before giving up.

hope this might help you.